# Project Euler: 413

Tags: php, math

I'm trying to solve the latest Project Euler problem using brute force ( I know it's not the best solution, but till I figure out, where I'm mistaken, I'll just use that ).

I can't understand, what exactly am I doing wrong here. I'm pretty sure that I generate the correct numbers, but the outcome is still wrong with the provided numbers:

```
function number_split( $nb )
{
    GLOBAL $arr;
    $length = strlen( $nb );
    if( $length == 1 )
        return true;

    $count = 0;
    for( $i=1; $i<$length; $i++ ) {
        for( $j=0; $j<=$length-$i; $j++ ) {
            $temp = substr( $nb, $j, $i );
            if( $temp % $length == 0 ) {
                $count++;   
                if( $count > 1 )
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return ( $count == 1 );
}

$lim = 3;
$res = 0;
$start = gmp_strval( gmp_pow( 10, $lim-1 ) );
$end = gmp_strval( gmp_pow( 10, $lim ) );
for( $i=$start; $i<$end; $i++ ) {
    $res += number_split( $i );
}
echo $res;
```

I get 378 where there should be 389. What am I doing wrong here?

I don't want an answer, just a hitch on where my logic is wrong.

---

The problem:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only looking at 3-digit numbers, but you need to look at all numbers under 10^3, which includes 1-digit and 2-digit numbers. In other words, `$start` should be `1`.

Additionally, you aren't looking at the substring which is the entire original string, because `$i` (the length of the substring) only runs up to `$length - 1`.

Comment: `For example, 5671 is a 4-digit one-child number. Among all its sub-strings 5, 6, 7, 1, 56, 67, 71, 567, 671 and 5671`. The example clearly states, that the number itself is also used.

Comment: @DainisAbols: Yes, the number *should* be used but your code doesn't use it.

Comment: Thanx a lot, I think I got it ( although my script will run for a while to prove it ). I was also looking wrong at 1 and 2-digit numbers when searching for 3 digit ones ;)

Comment: I figured I should explain why brute force doesn't work.  Assume that you had some super awesome instruction set that had an instruction for testing for one child numbers in only one clock cycle.  On a 3GHz machine, the testing of 10^19 numbers (not even considering cycles used to execute the loop or any additional logic) would take (10^19)/(3*10^9) = 3333333333.33 seconds = 105.699 years