# Project Euler 413

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I'm trying to solve [Project Euler's 413rd](http://projecteuler.net/problem=413) problem, and I think euler's trying to troll me.
To be honest, this problem doesn't seem to be complex, at least if someone applies brute force.

But, although my F function returns the right '9' when the argument is '10', it returns **413** when N=10^3... For christ's sake, this is the problem's index.

Does anyone else faced the same problem? The same number, perhaps, for F(10^3)? I don't seek for numerical solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730425/project-euler-413

Comment: Ok, I just ask if someone else gets F(1000)=413. Just this...
If you'd like, I could ask my question to the other post...

Comment: It would help if you posted your code, that way people can help you find the problem.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to post my code right now, but I maybe post it another time... I really do not believe that my code has bugs.. I mean that I get all sustring in the right way and I check every substring for being one-child number - I believe - properly... But...
I have to admit it. It's a bug for sure...

Comment: I'm getting 413 too. If I figure out what I did wrong, I'll post it here.

Comment: You should ask the question at http://forum.projecteuler.net/viewforum.php?f=50

Comment: I answered below why you're getting 413: You're handling substrings which start with 0 incorrectly. That said, Luka is correct in that you need a different approach.

Answer (score 4):

Time to solve using brute force (or why your approach does not work):

Using 10 operations per number it takes 
10^19 * 10 = 10^20 operations.

If you have 3Ghz proc and 10 cores and can do one operation per core you would need

10^20/(3*10^9 * 10) seconds to solve.

That is approximately 100 years.

I can confirm test cases correct

Comment: Thanks Luka, your answer is quite enlightening... I may have to consider another approach, more clever...

Answer (score 0):

I got 413 when my isOneChild(n) function recursively removed digits and checked at each level. I got the correct answer, 389. when I changed it to index into each substring.

Your solution does not correctly branch when there is leading 0's. For example, "00" should branch to "0" and "0", yielding a count of 2, but your solution only goes to "0", yielding a count of 1. Similarly, "01" branches only to "1", incorrectly yielding a count of 0.

Minimal fix: track a String in addition to the value.